# There are no workflows asscoiated with this list. Select another action

Tags: workflow

SP Office 365
SP 2013 designer

Create a reusable workflow and associated to item list
Workflow is show under workflow setting of that item list
Can strat workflow manullay or upon creating a new item

when trying to use retention policy under Action - Start a workflow

Error: There are no workflows asscoiated with this list. Select another action

Help

Comment: Only 2010 Workflows are supported for retention policies. Is this a 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 1):

This is cause by this problem
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894497/

you need to create your workflow as SP2010 to by pass the issue , i am also looking for a permanent workaround